# What is the current (April 2023) browser support for Ed25519 certificate signatures?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser, ecc

It seems that Firefox and Chrome both support x25519 keys, but they do not accept keys signed using Ed25519. Am I correct?
If so, where can I find the official source of this information?

Comment: The question's title seems to be about accepting certificates that are _signed with_ Ed25519. The body of the questions seems to be about accepting Ed25519 signatures of x25519 ECDH session keys, that is certificates _for_ Ed25519 signature keys, a different thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct, currently neither Chrome nor Firefox support the [EdDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA) signature scheme (i.e. neither Ed25519 nor Ed448).

For Firefox, there is a [Bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325335) open regarding support for Ed25519 in NSS, the crypto library used by Firefox.

Chrome is currently trialing Ed25519 in the Web Cryptography API. See the associated [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370697) for details. Still, this is not the same as support for Ed25519 in certificates/TLS handshakes. I was unable to find an offical ticket tracking Ed25519 support in TLS handshakes for Chrome/Chromium, but the [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/cert/pki/verify_signed_data.cc#147) indicates that this is definetly not supported.

As noted in the Bugzilla ticket, certificates with Ed25519 keys are currently forbidden by the [Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-v2.0.0.pdf). All public Certificate Authorities have to adhere to the Baseline Requirements, so this key type is likely rarely used in X.509 certificates, as it can only be used for non-public certificates.

X25519 on the other hand, a Diffie-Hellmann key exchange using Curve25519 is well supported in browsers. Firefox has supported X25519 since approximately 2016 ([old bugzilla ticket tracking inclusion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=957105)). Chrome has supported X25519 since Chrome 50 according to [Chromestatus](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5682529109540864).

Comment: If I have Ed25519 public private keypair, is there a way to deterministically generate X25519 keys to sign an X509 certificate that would be accepted by modern browsers?

Comment: X25519 is a Diffie-Hellman function. You cannot sign anything with it. Both X25519 and Ed25519 are based on Curve25519, but otherwise are distinct algorithms with different applications (one is a key exchange method, the other is a signature scheme). As above, currently none of the major browsers supports a signature scheme based on Curve25519 in TLS.